# Spring websevice, single wsdl but different WS provider, performance issue

Tags: multithreading, spring-ws

I am facing a performance issue. In my project, I have a webservice client which gives a call to hardware entity to get its status and other parameter's value. I am using Soap based Spring WS.
I have approx 5000 devices to which I need to make call in parallel using 100-500 threads at a time.

With a single call, it takes less than 5 second per device which is expected.

But when in multi-threading, the time keeps on increasing from 5 seconds to 30 sec and further more, more than 100 seconds even, device per device. And it takes more than 30 min  for all devices which should be less than 2 min as per requirement.

- We have different uri for each device so we gets URI dynamically so we use Spring's webServiceTemplate's method-  marshalSendAndReceive(String uri, Object requestPayload, WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback).
- WebServiceTemplate object is singleton.
- Only 1 wsdl but different devices are different WS provider.

Somewhere I found that it might be an issue with marshallers so I have increased the number of marshallers object for singleton webServiceTemplate object but this also didn't work.

Please share me idea to solve such issue. If need more info in order to solve this issue, please let me know if I missed to share any info.

**Elaborating some more about the question:**

Thanks hagrawal, yes threads cannot increase the response time but somewhere threads are taking time which I am not able to understand but yes, it is taking time when calls to actual webservice to talk to devices. I have taken start and end time to measure the timing for that call and found that first few 100 devices, the time taken is less that 3-4 sec but after that, the time taken keeps on increasing for further devices.

I have checked the JVM also and could not find any issue related to memory but yes, found so many threads blocked multiple times. Looks like these blocking threads consumes most of the time. I have taken the stack trace of those blocked threads, as below.

pool-111757-thread-1 [13184] (BLOCKED)

- sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateConnectionKeys line: 1266
- sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateKeys line: 1112
- sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone line: 1078
- sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage line: 348
- sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop line: 979
- sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record line: 914
- sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord line: 1062
- sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake line: 1375
- sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.starHandshake line: 1403
- sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake line: 1387
- org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket line: 275
- org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket line: 254
- org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect line: 123
- org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect line: 318

Again just to inform, the time taken increasing for the method when calling to actual ws of devices.

Comment: Your issue is really not very clear, more number of threads cannot increase the response time of device, you have to check whether time is really consumed by thread in the JVM or whether device is taking time to respond .. Marhsalling and unmarhalling are also very time consuming things if not done properly, but this will be the case only when you can confirm that time is spent by thread in the JVM .. May be you can put your marshal/unmarhsal code ..

Comment: when you say "Marhsalling and unmarhalling are also very time consuming things if not done properly" what is that supposed to mean?
Does that mean that at the time of creation, we need to do something for the marshallers and un-marshallers to work properly.

Comment: For example, if you are using JAXB then before marshalling you have to create JAXBContext, and if you do not handle properly then you will end up creating a time consuming process, read this http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2015/07/jvm-buzzwords-java-developers-should.html .. From your call stack  of `pool-111757-thread-1` thread, it looks like there is some issue with establishing connection with device, is this new device at that time (for `pool-111757-thread-1`) or same old device with which a connection was already established ..

Comment: It could be possible that you are having connection establish issue, I think that thread `pool-111757-thread-1` would have timedout and would have never got connection with the device ??

Comment: connection establishment is fine with all the device when try connecting them individually. The issue occurs only when we hit all the device at the same time. As the time passes, for starting few devices, the result is good and within the 3-4 seconds but gradually the time taken by devices keeps on increasing. Eg: for first 100-200 devices it is 3-4 sec and then next 201-500 devices, it would be 9-10 sec and then 501 to 1000 devices, it is 17-18 sec and so on and thus hits the performance badly. Whereas our requirement is to get all those response within few seconds.

Comment: If we talk about marshallers, so just to share that, we create Spring WebServiceTemplate at the time of server startup which has marshallers etc already. At the run time we use this WebServiceTemplate object.

Comment: When taken stacktrace of threads, the original issue seems to have making connection with some devices after sometime. Those thread block count is also from 10 to 300-1000. I am using tomcat server in client, is there something like which can not have more connections to network very often?

Comment: Above in main question, it is just an example for one of the blocked thread.